# How can I insert data to my json file and save it in local with AS3?

Tags: json, actionscript-3, air

How can I insert data to my json file and save it?

```
private function readAndWrite() {

        listJson = new URLLoader();
        listJson.load(new URLRequest("readText.json"));
        listJson.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseListJson);
    }
    private function parseListJson(evt: Event) {

        readJsonList = JSON.parse(listJson.data);
        var numberOfBooks = readJsonList.BookList.length
        readJsonList.BookList[numberOfBooks] = {
            Name: "Hello World"
        }

        for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfBooks; i++) {
            trace(readJsonList.BookList[i].Name)
        }
```

/////////////////////////////This one not working////////////

```
        var file: File = new File("readText.json");
        trace(file +" :file name")
        var stream: FileStream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
        stream.writeUTFBytes(readJsonList.BookList as String);
        stream.close();
    }
```

And here is my JSON file

```
 {
   "List": [
    {
      "Name":"somename01"
    },
   {
      "Name":"somename02"
   }
  ],
   "assets": "", 
   "modes":     [  "0", "1", "2" ]
}
```

Now I want to insert more data to my list items...

Comment: These are the error I am getting..

ArgumentError: Error #2004: One of the parameters is invalid.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.filesystem::File/set nativePath()
 at flash.filesystem::File()
 at Function/loadApp/private:readAndWrite/parseListJson()[/Volumes/Backup/Projects/2016/AppDesign/Platform/loadApp.as:101]
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

--
My head is spinning

Comment: try a full path instead of the file name at `new File("readText.json")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `path` parameter of the [`File` constructor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#File()) is supposed to be a full file path, not a relative path like `"readText.json"`.

Alternatively, instead of using a full file path you typically use [`resolvePath`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#resolvePath()) to [find a file relative to a known directory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a4c56-7fc4).

Example:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("readText.json");
```

Comment: Rather, I have used text file.

Comment: Thanks anyways ... I appreciate, Aaron